# In C, what constitutes an "undefined reference" to a symbol?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, undefined-symbol

I was reading the GNU documentation on the GCC linker's `--wrap` option, which can be used to mock functions for testing.

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html says the following:

> --wrap symbol
>
> Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to __wrap_symbol. Any undefined reference to __real_symbol will be resolved to symbol. This can be used to provide a wrapper for a system function. The wrapper function should be called __wrap_symbol. If it wishes to call the system function, it should call __real_symbol.

I've noticed that it says **Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to __wrap_symbol**, but it doesn't say what exactly an *undefined reference to symbol* means. Does anyone know specifically what is considered *undefined*?

I'm confused because I created an example program that successfully mocks the `read` function (it's compiled with `gcc test.c -o test -Wl,--wrap=read` to enable mocking). How come the linker considers this symbol undefined? I included `unistd.h`, so shouldn't that make `read` defined? I thought the documentation said `--wrap` only works on undefined symbols?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DUMMY_STR "I don't care because this function is mocked."
#define DUMMY_LEN (strlen(DUMMY_STR))

ssize_t __wrap_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
   sprintf(buf, DUMMY_STR);
   return DUMMY_LEN;
}

int main()
{
   char buf[128] = {'\0'};
   puts("Press anything, then ENTER, to continue");
   read(1, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
   puts(buf);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I expect it just means the symbol references listed in the object module. If the compiler/assembler sees a definition and a use of a symbol in the same file, it might resolve it locally and not report the reference in the object module (or it might be deliberately designed not to do that, so that `--wrap` will work for these cases). Otherwise, the assembler generates an object file that lists the reference as something that needs resolution by the linker. That is an undefined reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including the header file just *declares* the symbols, it does not *define* them -- they'll be *undefined* in your test.c compilation unit because it does not ever define them.

The read symbol is in fact *defined* in libc.so -- the C standard library -- but when linking your program it first sees your compilation unit (test.o) at which point read is still *undefined*.  So the references to `read` are instead mapped to `__wrap_read`.

*definitions* and *declarations* are two different things.  Related, but different.

Comment: Alright, that really clarifies things, thank you. I sometimes get declare and define mixed up.